# Hyper-v fail to start any virtual machine - an invalid Handler was specified

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

After the last anniversary update of windows 10 (of august 2) hyper-v fail to start any of the virtual machine, new or old.

The message I get is "Virtual Machine Name" failed to start worker process: An invalid HANDLE was specified. (0xC0000008).

[image: Error dialog]

I have try many thinks, and look all over the internet bug I can not find solution.

1. I have totally remove and re-install the hyper-v
2. I have check for correct permissions on the directories of the vm
3. I have run Process Monitor to see why is crash
4. I have read the debug report that send to MS
5. I have made from scratch new test virtual machines, for both generations.

after all that is still not runs...

Any idea is appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same issue and also found no solution jet.

I've also installed the latest BIOS - no success.

My specs are:
 - Win 10 Pro (Build 1607)
 - MainBoard: ASUS X99 Deluxe
 - CPU: i7-5820K

I'll check my drivers now and then I'll give the SFC a try...

Edit1:

Updated / Re-Installed some drivers now - no success

SFC running..

Edit2:

SFC had no success eighter.

Edit3:

I found that COMODO Internet Security is the problem at hand. Uninstalling it & rebooting fixed the issue. But with no virus protection left, this isn't a good solution.

At the COMODO Forum there is a thread for this issue, too. We should wait what COMODO finds out:
https://forums.comodo.com/bug-reports-cis/comodo-firewall-began-conflict-with-hyperv-t116351.0.html

Comment: I have made the same with no success either

Comment: Can't believe that we're the only two having this issue. It's sad that there is still no solution for this. I don't want to re-setup the whole host mashine -.-...

Comment: I can not agree more with you. And even if you re-setup the system I am not believe that the issue will go.

Comment: Ok. I found some posting saying, that Comodo Anti-Virus can be the problem. I'll check this myself now. Do you use Comodo, too?

Comment: Yes I have but I was uninstall it for test and I have the same problem

Comment: Uninstalling COMODO & restarting the computer fixed the problem!

Comment: and now what ? we must remove comodo ?

Comment: found that : https://forums.comodo.com/bug-reports-cis/comodo-firewall-began-conflict-with-hyperv-t116351.0.html

Comment: =D found that, too. Edited my answer above, too.

Comment: Comodo is not the fault - Hyper-v Crash !, hyper-v must fix it... anyway thank you for the effort...

Comment: Comodo fix the error.

Comment: I just experienced the same with iShadow Virtual Display Manager (virtual monitor solution). Hyper-V worked again after uninstalling the software. I sent a message to the vendor.

Comment: iShadow VDM was very prompt to resolve this. For me, this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with a test virtual environment in Hyper-V which was working perfectly on my Windows 10 machine.

I installed Intel Unite Software on my PC and could no longer start any Hyper-V VM. I then uninstalled this software it began working immediately. I would recommend uninstalling any non-vital programs you've installed recently, prior to when Hyper-V stopped functioning.

I am looking into this software to see what component caused this and will update if I gent anything more useful. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Today **Comodo Firewall** update their drivers `inspect.sys` and was signed by Microsoft, and hyper-v starts working again with out the above message.

The [working Comodo Firewall](https://forums.comodo.com/news-announcements-feedback-cis/comodo-internet-security-8405165-build-is-released-t116693.0.html) version on files is **8.4.0.5165**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, uninstalling mirrorop virtual driver resolved this issue. I think every virtual driver can result in this kind of issue.

Comment: what is that driver ? where and how you uninstall it ?, please give some more informations - this error by the way was a problem coming from comodo firewall and now have been fixed.